# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to add card view in my XML but I keep getting this exception

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

I am using the google code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
... >
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[Create Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView)

I have even added the card view jar. I am using eclipse for dev.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If your using Android Studio then add the following dependency in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jar file and simply import  the cardview-v7 library project from the `/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support` and add it as library project to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the jar for CardView. It is not included in other components. You can find it in the support-v7 folder adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview/libs. Include this in your project

Comment: Yes I have included tha

Comment: right click your project, go to properties -->java build path -->order and export. Check if the library is checked. Sometimes it doesnt get included. After including the library, clean and build your project and then run it.

Comment: Did that. Still the same issue

Comment: what does the outer linear layout do?

Comment: It is just a container for holding views. Nothing more

Comment: are you inflating this view inside a ListView or Recycler View?

Comment: Inflating inside listview

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to do following to add `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` as a library project and also add + check it's jar file in java build path

1. Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace --> Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) -> Click ok -> Click Finish
2. Right click on cardview project -> Properties -> Android -> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) -> Apply -> ok
3. Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android -> Add -> cardview -> apply -> ok
4. right click on your project again -> build path -> configure build path ->under libraries->add jar->expand cardview->expand libs->select android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar
5. under order and export ->check android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar ->click ok
6. Make sure you select the Android 5.0 in Properties -> Android-> Project Build Target

Comment: I have done this way too many times. But still the same issue keeps appearing.

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. I had switched to Android Studio and it works fine over there. Never faced the issue again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with the eclipse. But I have moved my project to studio and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

check out whether you added the right dependency

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
   }
```

The version number  26.1.0  should be same as

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/card_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_margin="2dp"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
  android:layout_height="300dp">
```